# How to launch Tasker Task from app drawer? Can't move shortcut from home screen into app drawer

Tags: tasker, home-screen-shortcuts, app-widgets, nova-launcher

I have created a shortcut/widget to link to a Task in Tasker. This shortcut/widget appears on the home screen. I don't like the clutter and would like to move it into the app drawer. How can I do this? I tried dragging it but how can I open the app drawer while dragging? I tried opening the app drawer and holding down in an empty area to see if the option comes up to create a widget, but it doesn't. I am using Nova Launcher.

In other words, how can I launch a Tasker Task from the app drawer?

Comment: If your device is rooted, you can possibly assign the shortcut to that task to navigation bar buttons (I do this, with MacroDroid, another automation app) or even volume keys // That aside, it may be easier to choose a launcher (or check if your launcher can) add additional screens and add that widget there. AFAIK, widgets can't be launched from app drawer but then it may be possible IDK

Comment: Reading your question again, Nova Launcher allows you to add as many screens as you like

Comment: @beeshyams this is true but I'd prefer it go in the app drawer than on another home screen. I thought this would have been easy.

Comment: Adding to the app drawer *usually* needs changing [the app's manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro#components) that is done on install-time, not run-time. Adding a home screen shortcut doesn't have this restriction though.

Comment: You can use Tasker App factory to turn your task into an app. Then it would be available in app drawer. Otherwise, you have to ask Nova launcher developer to provide feature  to add custom shortcuts in app drawer.